# call a function when we click on the post title

Tags: wordpress

On the front page of my testing WordPress site I have 10 posts. When we click on the post title or post featured image, it takes us to that particular post . 
I want to call a function on my plugin, when we click title or image.
Is there any **add_action()** for that ? or suggest me how can we achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the function "get_permalink".

It can be found in the following file-
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/link-template.php